# Container networking on between docker hosts on different VMs

Tags: networking, docker, virtual-machine

I have 3 Ubuntu VMs atop virtualbox. Each VMs have docker installed. I have the same container running on each of the docker hosts. Is it possible to let the docker containers communicate without using a SWARM or overlay network.

Answer (score 1):

Swarm mode or overlay networking are the easy answers. With support from your router, you can use macvlan or the experimental ipvlan networking drivers. There's also exposed ports or host networking if communication doesn't need to be directly to the container.

Without any of those options, you can manually update the routing table and firewall rules on each host, but this is non trivial.